# how to create graph in grafana using Json data?

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I have a sample json & I'm using JSON API plugin as i'm getting data from API

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "timeStamp": "2022-07-28 12:00:00",
            "val": 10
        },
        {
            "timeStamp": "2022-07-28 13:00:00",
            "val": 11
        },
        {
            "timeStamp": "2022-07-28 14:00:00",
            "val": 20
        },
        {
            "timeStamp": "2022-07-28 15:00:00",
            "val": 30
        },
        {
            "timeStamp": "2022-07-28 16:00:00",
            "val": 35
        },
        {
            "timeStamp": "2022-07-28 17:00:00",
            "val": 39
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to make graph using this data in grafana. Where X-axis should be time & y-axis should some number.

How can I plot graph from this data?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Infinity plugin, to visualise your data as timeseries:
[image]

in my case I needed to add data transformation, to treat timeStamp as time:

[image]

I used API mocking service:
https://somegrafanademo.free.beeceptor.com/

to present data:

[image]

Comment: Hi Maciej,

We use Grafana on-prem v9.1.7 and trying to display data from the following endpoint - 
`https://status.snowflake.com/`.

Please let us know if we need to set up the Snowflake data source for this or we could use another solution to get the data.

For example, if we could add the api endpoint to the prometheus targets and be able to scrape this data. -
`https://status.snowflake.com/api/v2/summary.json`

Thanks,
Eugene